# How to call methods of Model Class in Interactive Console locally?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have been searching this since yesterday and still nothing. From all that researching this is my understanding so far.

- You can access your datastore remotely with remote_api_shell.py
- Make sure your path is set correctly in your Environment variable.

And according to my understanding the remote datastore that they were talking about is the datastore in appspot.com and not the local one. I don't want to deploy my app right now and hence I want to just work locally, for now atleast.

I created a model named Usersdb in my app. As someone coming from PHP, MYSQL background I thought GQL would have console environment for us to test the queries. But after some googling I found out that you can manipulate local datastore from the interactive console that's in

```
http://localhost:8081/_ah/admin/interactive
```

From the post [Google App Engine GQL query on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460112/google-app-engine-gql-query-on-localhost) I got the idea of performing GqlQuery in the interactive console while in localhost which goes something like this:-

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Userdb where username = 'random_user'")
print q.get().username
```

But what I really wanted to do was perform method calls like get_by_id() and get_by_key_name() and such in my interactive console without having to test on my app. Like:-

```
print Userdb.get_by_id(12)
```

How can I get those running? Do I have to import my python file to the interactive console? I tried doing that too but it crashed app engine. I'm just starting out on app engine. Forgive me if this is a completely stupid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should import the model class that you wrote into your session in the interactive console. For example, if you have a file named `model.py` in your application, which contains your `Userdb` class you could write the following in the interactive console:

```
import model

print model.Userdb.get_by_id(12)
```

Comment: Awesome!! It works. But I noticed something though. My file name is called main.py by default and while importing that file (main.py) it somehow crashes app engine after processing the query. I renamed the file, edited my app.yaml file and it no longer is crashing. Strange. Anyone know why?

Comment: If you've got all your code in a single file (like main.py) it's possible that something other than your model definitions is interacting poorly with the interactive console. For example, the 'application =' line in this example (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/usingwebapp) might have unintended side-effects if executed within the console.